# Magento cart does not display products, but does show the total price

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, magento-1.8

I am running a Magento 1.8 multistore with around 10 different shops.
On one of the shops I am experiencing a weird bug, the shopping cart stays empty, but gives me a total of the added products (see image)

[image: image 1]

I am running default /template/checkout files. and some of my other stores do as well, but they do not have this problem.

I checked almost every option in the admin, but i cannot find a option that relates to this.

The web unfortunately didn't give me answers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this happen always or just sometimes ? Do you have the possibility to debug your template files or check log files ? There might be an error with the template output (checkout/cart/item/default.phtml) causing this (if it happens all of the time).

Comment: As far as i can see now (multiple pc, on this network and external) this problem happens everytime. i'll check the log files now. thanks

Comment: Did you check the error/exception log ? If you put a die('test') in checkout/cart/item/default.phtml, does it die or doesn't it do anything ?

Comment: And a follow-up: I can't find anything related to the theme or problem in my logs, also, why do other sites work fine that run on the same core files and core template, but if i let this site use core template file (or any other design for that matter) this problem persists.

Comment: the die doesnt do anything, i think that's because the default.phtml doesnt get loaded. When i enable tamplate path hints it doesnt show, while it does with other sites

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same skin as the other sites ?

Comment: yeah, i use exactly the same skin (changed the design in the backend) For the checkout part both design use frontend/base/default/template/checkout and the site that works displays the default.phtml (template path hints on) and the problem site doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by making a new store, set all settings as the old one and assign the design to it. 
still no clue to what the cause of the problem was.